# Query emp table in oracle 19c

Tags: sql, database, oracle

make a java program that queries the inbuilt table “emp” and display the first two columns (empno using column index and ename using column name ) of all the rows.

But problem here is :
ERROR:
ORA-04043: object emp does not exist

I am using oracle 19c on windows platform and using pluggable database orclpdb user "hr".

please tell me where to find this emp table.

And second question :
Even if I manually create a new Emp table in hr user ,what will be the sql command for the given

/*
 *  Using
 *   queries the inbuilt table “emp” and 
 *   displays the first two columns 
 *   (empno using column index and ename using column name )
 *    of all the rows.

*/
just tell me the sql command only.

Comment: `emp` table does not exist in the HR schema. It must be `EMPLOYEES`. see [oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/comsc/HR-sample-schema-table-descriptions.html#GUID-F7D0013F-A4F2-4310-9FF2-316889850D93)

Comment: one question per post please. If the table emp does not exist you'll have to create it first. The emp and dept scripts have been around since the beginning of oracle. You can google them or download them from livesql (https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_O5AEB2HE08PYEPTGCFLZU9YCV.html) and then run them.

Comment: For 2nd question, SO is not a homework writing service. Try to solve it yourself, do research. If you get stuck, post a new question explaining what you have done, where you get stuck, what errors you got.